# Quickest way to get last or oldest post date - WP Query

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, query-posts, get-posts

I know how to get the last or oldest post data using following code

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'order_by' => 'publish_date',
  'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

**And then I will get the date from the first array itself, but is there any quickest way to get that ?**

Comment: You can use custom query  $oldest_post_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT `id` FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE `post_type` = 'post' AND `post_status` = 'publish' ORDER BY `post_date` ASC");

Answer (score 3):

```
function is_first() {
    global $post;
    $loop = get_posts( 'numberposts=1&order=ASC' );
    $first = $loop[0]->ID; 
    return ( $post->ID == $first ) ? true : false;
}
```

you can use this too

Comment: This also works, but for me this was the best one $oldest_post_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_date FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date ASC");